# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

Tags: jsp, jsf

i need to pass this parameter values into other page.  how can i get the values from on it thank for advance... i'm waiting for ur reply

```
 <a href="return1.jsp?bid=<%= rs.getString("bid") %>? isbn=<%=rs.getString("isbn")%>? bdate=<%= rs.getString("bdate") %>? rdate=<%= rs.getString("rdate") %>? mid=<%=rs.getString("mid")  %>"> 
       <input type="button" value="Return" class="btn btn-primary" /></a>
```

But i get error like this..

```
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8? isbn=008? bdate=2014-08-03? rdate=2014-8-9? mid=76"
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.internalIntrospecthelper(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:361)
```

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of options you can choose:

- Use Javascript to get the values and change windows location to target page
- Server side to get parameter and redirect to other page with those parameters
- Or server side forward instead of redirect.

It need more information to know your code.

As for your exception, the problem is that a HTTP query string should use "&" instead of "?" to combine parameters.

You can try to change to below:

```
 <a href="return1.jsp?bid=<%= rs.getString("bid") %>&isbn=<%=rs.getString("isbn")%>&bdate=<%= rs.getString("bdate") %>&rdate=<%= rs.getString("rdate") %>&mid=<%=rs.getString("mid")  %>">
```

Comment: If this answers your question, you can accept this answer, :)

Comment: You can accept an answer like this: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s46/sh/03f7676d-1837-4ab6-8d8d-efb381b29148/91e7c9762188782ea6f422194b17483d